# adyen integration to React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, in-app-billing, adyen

Good Day everyone.. 
Does anyone know how to integrate [adyen](https://www.adyen.com/) to **React Native** which works on both **IOS and ANDROID**.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the 'react bridge module'`<React/RCTBridgeModule.h>` you are able to wrap native libraries into Javascript.

Using methods `RCT_EXPORT_MODULE` and `RCT_EXPORT_METHOD` you are able to wrap individual functions, with some degree of flexibility regarding naming and parameters.

React bridge module supports auto type conversion from the native code, making the wrapping of functions faster.

Documentation and example code
 IOS: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

 Android: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html

Answer (score 1):

Adyen has recently released a BETA version of the official react-native support. It is still in progress, but a good point to start.

https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-react-native

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31478147)

Answer (score 0):

There is a RN wrapper for Adyen library here. https://github.com/YouriT/react-native-adyen-drop-in

You should check the Adyen version, the library is not using the latest version.